# How to model 1'000'000'000 cells in React?

Tags: reactjs, performance

So I want to display a large table, say 1 billion cells.

The component receives remote updates, each addressing one cell.

Each cell is represented via a `div`

Here's a naive implementation, which won't be practical, because on each update a large array is created and all cells are updated.

```
const Table = props => {
  const [cells, setCells] = useState(new Array[1_000_000_000])
  // ...  'useEffect()' receives remote data and 'setCells()' it.
  return cells.map(cell => <div id={cell.id}>{cell.text}</div>)
}
```

How to implement this efficiently so that performance is top notch?

Ideally, I would like that on each update only 1 array element is updated and only 1 table cell in DOM is updated ‍♂️ Ideally the solution should be O(1) and work great for tables of 10 to 1'000'000'000 cells. Is it possible in React?

By *1'000'000'000 cells* I mean a large number of cells that browser can display at once if cells are created and updated with Vanilla JavaScript.

I'm looking not for a library but for a pattern. I want to find out what is the general approach in React for such cases. It is obvious how to do this in Vanilla JavaScript, you just create `div`s and then access the required `div` and update its `innerText` ‍♂️. But how this case can be modeled in React?

Comment: Maybe you can implement pagination.

Comment: @Prime It's not an answer to the question I've asked 

Comment: what you mean by "efficiently", how to measure that ? how long does it take to update one cell is considered as "efficiently".

Comment: Try it with only 1 000 000 cells.  Get that working and optimized.  Then 10 000 000, etc.  With that you can give us a more specific question about the roadblocks you encounter.

Comment: @thelonglqd Generally cell update should take the same amount of time for table of 10 cells and table of 1'000'000'000 cells. O(1) solution. ‍♂️ Hope you understand.

Comment: @RickJames You see the code, it works fine for table of 10 cells. The solution for 1'000'000'000 cells should be completely different, you can't get it incrementally ‍♂️

Comment: Try it, and if you think it is not optimized in React, please submit a PR for them, I think you're welcome :)

Comment: @thelonglqd Also, read the question, there's an explanation of efficiency: 'Ideally, I would like that on each update only 1 array element is updated and only 1 table cell in DOM is updated'

Comment: Did you tried it ? And the does current React implementation meets your need and how do you know that (profiler, etc.). You should provide more information about what you've tried for ease of getting help.

Comment: @thelonglqd Of course I tried, read the question. The code doesn't scale. It's not O(1).

Comment: Yeah, read more about the key props in list and virtual DOM in React to know how it works. What you need is the nature of React indeed, you do not need anything else.

Comment: @thelonglqd I'm not looking for a general advice from a stranger. Obviously you don't have an answer for the question. So lets end this pointless message exchange 

Comment: If it is Order(N*N), you will be in trouble even at 1000.  A billion `<div>` tags in the DOM would probably need a terabyte of RAM.  Humor us and step your way up.

Answer (score 2):

For very long lists, "virtualized list" is the typical approach so that only some of the cells are actually mounted and the rest are temporarily rendered with placeholders. A couple libraries that implement this are:

- https://react-window.now.sh/
- https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized

Comment: I'm looking not for a library but for a pattern. I want to find out what is the general approach in React for such cases. It is obvious how to do this in Vanilla JS, you just create `div`s and then access the required `div` and update its innerText ‍♂️. But how this case can be modeled in React?

Comment: `mounted` is diffrent from `update`, he asked about update a cell in huge react table, I think.

Comment: @bxq That *is* the pattern; if your data has appropriate keys at worst it'd only update the row with the changed cell. Not that a browser could render such a thing in a meaningful way anyway--hence various forms of displaying partial data.

Comment: @DaveNewton If we are talking about the code in my example. Update of 1 cell arrives. You have to create a new Array of 1'000'000'000 elements for `setCells()` call, that is already inefficient. Then `cells.map()` runs over 1'000'000'000, that is also inefficient.

Comment: @bxq As you mention below, the immutable libraries don't typically allocate an entirely new array (again with the caveat that most (all?) browsers wouldn't know what to do with a billion-element array anyway). That's why the "pattern" is some version of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for strictly O(1) then typical React patterns may not suitable since React cannot partially render a component. In other words, the render method of your Table component will need to iterate over the list in O(n). Virtualization of the list could reduce from O(size of list) to O(size of window).

---

You may be able to workaround this by maintaining a list of React refs of each mounted cell, then calling an update method on the single cell by index to trigger a re-render of a single cell, but this is likely not recommended usage of React.

---

Another option could be the Vanilla JS approach inside of a stateful React component. You'll want to implement the relevant lifecycle methods for mounting and un-mounting, but the update would be handled in Vanilla JS.

```
class Table {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.container = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Append 1_000_000_000 cells into this.container.current

        // Later, modify this.container.current.item(index) text
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Perform any cleanup
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.container} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Array can be replaced with a `List` from `Immutable JS` 

Comment: @bxq Thanks you're correct, I've updated my answer to describe the render behavior of React instead.